# Ubuntu: automatically shown popup dialog is annoying. Can I disable it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

When I choose 'copy link address' from context menu or just select URL text, following popup dialog is automatically shown.

[image]

It is annoying for me because this popup dialog grabs keyboard focus from current working application.
How do I disable this popup?

I'm using following version.

```
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Comment: This must be a thing with firefox. Since i use same 12.04.2 ubuntu, but not firefox. I use google chrome and i dont see this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have an addon to Firefox that is causing this behavior. I'm using Ubuntu 13.04, and I see nothing of the sort, nor do I remember seeing anything like that with any previous version of Ubuntu. You might check your addons (Tools > Addons or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in Firefox).